# Conditionally displaying RenderBody based on Screen Size

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to use media queries in my `_Layout.cshtml` to determine which Nav bar is displayed.

On larger devices I want to display a vertical nav bar using Bootstrap (`col-2`) and I want to `RenderBody()` (`col-10`) with the Horizontal nav bar not displayed.

On smaller devices the Horizontal nav bar is displayed the full width of the screen and `RenderBody()` would be below.

I'm not sure if the media queries actually work because the following error is displayed.

```
The "RenderBody" method has already been called.
```

So my question is how can I conditionally Render based on the size of the screen?

Please note that I'm just trying to piece this together as I go and am by no means an expert. Far from it.

## _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @* @Styles.Render("~/Content/css") *@
    @*@Styles.Render("~/Content")*@
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/strap4.css">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="~/Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/pure.css" rel="stylesheet">



</head>
<body>

    <!--==========================
      Top Bar
    ============================-->
    <section id="topbar" class="d-none d-lg-block">
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <div class="contact-info pull-left">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> <a href="mailto:shipleyswine@yahoo.com">shipleyswine@yahoo.com</a>
                <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Orders: 1-866-376-8986 (Toll Free) • 740-745-2911
            </div>
            <div class="social-links pull-right">
                <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/shipleyswine/" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/289480962/shipley-swine-genetics/" class="instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="google-plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!--==========================
      Header
    ============================-->
    <header id="header">
        <div class="container">

            <div id="logo" class="pull-left">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" class="scrollto"><img src="~/Assets/Images/ssHeader.png" height="40px" width="150px"></a>
            </div>



            <!-- #nav-menu-container -->
        </div>
    </header><!-- #header -->

    <div id="HorizontalNav" class="container">

        <div class="">

            <div class="breedOption" style="height:auto; margin:auto; text-align:center; position:relative;">
                <a href="@Url.Action("SelectBoar", "Boars", new { selectedBreed = "Yorkshire" })">
                    <img class="img-rounded img-responsive mx-auto" src="~/Assets/breedMenu/york.jpg" /><div id="imageText"class="w-100 h-100">Yorkshire</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="breedOption" style="height:auto; margin:auto; text-align:center; position:relative;">
                <a href="@Url.Action("SelectBoar", "Boars", new { selectedBreed = "Duroc" })">
                    <img class="img-rounded img-responsive mx-auto" src="~/Assets/breedMenu/duroc.jpg" /><div id="imageText"class="w-100 h-100">Duroc</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="breedOption" style="height:auto; margin:auto; text-align:center; position:relative;">
                <a href="@Url.Action("SelectBoar", "Boars", new { selectedBreed = "Berkshire" })">
                    <img class="img-rounded img-responsive mx-auto" src="~/Assets/breedMenu/berk.jpg" /><div  id="imageText"class="w-100 h-100">Berkshire</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="breedOption" style="height:auto; margin:auto; text-align:center; position:relative;">
                <a href="@Url.Action("SelectBoar", "Boars", new { selectedBreed = "Exotic" })">
                    <img class="img-rounded img-responsive mx-auto" src="~/Assets/breedMenu/exotic.jpg" /><div  id="imageText"class="w-100 h-100">Exotic</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="breedOption" style="height:auto; margin:auto; text-align:center; position:relative;">
                <a href="@Url.Action("SelectBoar", "Boars", new { selectedBreed = "Hampshire" })">
                    <img class="img-rounded img-responsive mx-auto" src="~/Assets/breedMenu/hamp.jpg" /><div  id="imageText"class="w-100 h-100">Hampshire</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="breedOption" style="height:auto; margin:auto; text-align:center; position:relative;">
                <a href="@Url.Action("SelectBoar", "Boars", new { selectedBreed = "Other" })">
                    <img class="img-rounded img-responsive mx-auto" src="~/Assets/breedMenu/Other.jpg" /><div id="imageText"class="w-100 h-100">Other</div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
    <a href="#">
        <div id="salealert" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            Summer Pricing, Most Boars up to 50% off!
        </div>
    </a>

    <div id="VerticleNav" class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <div class="pure-menu custom-restricted-width">
                <ul class="pure-menu-list">
                    <li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-selected text-center"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Boars</a></li>
                    <li class="pure-menu-item text-center w-100" style="display: inline-block;"><a href="@Url.Action("SelectBoar", "Boars", new { selectedBreed = "Yorkshire" })" class="pure-menu-link"><img class="rounded img-responsive mx-auto" src="~/Assets/breedMenu/york.jpg" style="height: 50%; width: 50%; max-height:40%; max-width: 40%;" /><div style="color: white; position: absolute;top: 70%;left: 50%; bottom: 5px;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">Yorkshire</div></a></li>
                    <li class="pure-menu-item text-center w-100" style="display: inline-block;"><a href="@Url.Action("SelectBoar", "Boars", new { selectedBreed = "Duroc" })" class="pure-menu-link"><img class="rounded img-responsive mx-auto" src="~/Assets/breedMenu/duroc.jpg" style="height: 50%; width: 50%; max-height:40%; max-width: 40%;" /><div style="color: white; position: absolute;top: 70%;left: 50%; bottom: 5px;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">Duroc</div></a></li>
                    <li class="pure-menu-item text-center w-100" style="display: inline-block;"><a href="@Url.Action("SelectBoar", "Boars", new { selectedBreed = "Berkshire" })" class="pure-menu-link"><img class="rounded img-responsive mx-auto" src="~/Assets/breedMenu/berk.jpg" style="height: 50%; width: 50%; max-height:40%; max-width: 40%;" /><div style="color: white; position: absolute;top: 70%;left: 50%; bottom: 5px;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">Berkshire</div></a></li>
                    <li class="pure-menu-item text-center w-100" style="display: inline-block;"><a href="@Url.Action("SelectBoar", "Boars", new { selectedBreed = "Exotic" })" class="pure-menu-link"><img class="rounded img-responsive mx-auto" src="~/Assets/breedMenu/exotic.jpg" style="height: 50%; width: 50%; max-height:40%; max-width: 40%;" /><div style="color: white; position: absolute;top: 70%;left: 50%; bottom: 5px;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">Exotic</div></a></li>
                    <li class="pure-menu-item text-center w-100" style="display: inline-block;"><a href="@Url.Action("SelectBoar", "Boars", new { selectedBreed = "Hampshire" })" class="pure-menu-link"><img class="rounded img-responsive mx-auto" src="~/Assets/breedMenu/hamp.jpg" style="height: 50%; width: 50%; max-height:40%; max-width: 40%;" /><div style="color: white; position: absolute;top: 70%;left: 50%; bottom: 5px;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">Hampshire</div></a></li>
                    <li class="pure-menu-item text-center w-100" style="display: inline-block;"><a href="@Url.Action("SelectBoar", "Boars", new { selectedBreed = "Other" })" class="pure-menu-link"><img class="rounded img-responsive mx-auto" src="~/Assets/breedMenu/Other.jpg" style="height: 50%; width: 50%; max-height:40%; max-width: 40%;" /><div style="color: white; position: absolute;top: 70%;left: 50%; bottom: 5px;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">Other</div></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
          @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="HorizontalNav">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

## CSS

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {

    #HorizontalNav{
        display:block;
    }

    #VerticleNav{
        display:none;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {

    #HorizontalNav {
        display: block;
    }

    #VerticleNav {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px){

    #HorizontalNav {
        display: none;
    }

    #VerticleNav {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}


#imageText {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    top: 0;
    /* left: 0; */
    /* right: 0; */
    /* bottom: 0; */
    /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-top: 40%;
    padding-left:2.5px;
    padding-right:2.5px;

}

.breedMenu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.breedOption {
    width: 16.66%;
    max-width: 16.66%;
    min-width: 16.66%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    background: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.boarlabel {
        padding-top: 83px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        font-family: AmericanCaptain, Calibri, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14pt;
        text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;

}

    .breedOption:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        color:black;
    }

    .breedOption a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: inherit;
    }


.listcontainer{
    height:auto;
}

#salealert {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:large;
    margin-top:20px;
}

#salealert:hover {
    background-color: #ffe6e6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use renderbody once. If you need a second renderbody, you can use RenderSection instead. Simply explained in the link.

https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-layout-viewstart-renderbody-and-rendersection/

Comment: How would i implement this such that the content is rendered the correct way? On larger screens it would be within a column but on smaller screens it would cover the whole width?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want to do.                                                      

_Layout -------------
                                                                                                                        
<div id="HorizontalNav">
        @RenderSection("horizontalSection",required:false)
</div>

IndexView ---------------

<div id="indexElements">
 //do something
</div>

@section horizontalSection{

 // You'd better use a partial view here.
 // @Html.RenderPartial("PartialView"); ----------
 <div id="sectionDiv">
 //do something
 </div>
}